# How many comparative sorting algorithms are there?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sorting, combinatorics, decision-tree

I've invented an abstract structure to represent a comparison-based sorting algorithm, which I will call a *comparison tree* (similar to the decision tree of a comparative sorting algorithm).  Specifically, a comparison tree is a full binary tree rooted at $s$ where each non-leaf node is labeled with an ordered pair $(x, y)$ such that for any vertex $w$, the path $sw$ contains no pair of vertices $u, v$ so that $u = v$. Each leaf $\lambda$ is labelled with a permutation of $1,2,\dots,n$.  The tree satisfies three properties:

1. Each permutation appears in one of the leaves of the tree.
2. For each leaf $\lambda$ and each $(x, y)$ occurring in the path $s\lambda$, we have $\lambda_x < \lambda_y$ if the left child of $(x, y)$ occurs in the path, and $\lambda_x > \lambda_y$ if otherwise.
3. For each leaf $\lambda$ and $\lambda_0 \neq \lambda$, assigning $\lambda_0$ to the leaf $\lambda$ will break the property 2.

By this definition, how many comparison trees are there, as a function of $n$?

Comment: $\lambda$ denotes a single leaf, and I'm saying that these 3 conditions must hold for all the leafs $\lambda$. A comparative sorting algorithm takes $n$ and an array of size $n$, and I'm saying that all the leafs $\lambda$ are a permutation of that (that also implies that they are the permutation of themselves), and all the permutations of the input array must be covered by the algorithm, that the condition $i)$ requires that.

Comment: Thank you.  Please check my edit to see whether it accurately reflects your intent.

Comment: $\lambda$ is not necessarily a permutation of $1, 2, ..., n$, as the input is not limited to that. It's okay anyway, as we can make this assumption without causing a change to the answer.

Comment: I can see that there need to be $n$ leaves - *input nodes*? But what is the significance of the root? Does not every input value need to reach *one* output node? You may be reinventing [sorting networks from 2-sorters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).